# what is wrong with the sql query in the java code

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
String sql = "UPDATE `test`.`books` SET ? = ? WHERE `isbn` = ?;";
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1,whatToUp);
            ps.setString(2, data);
            ps.setString(3, isbn);
            ps.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Statement executed");
            conn.close();
```

Error say that something is wrong with query . I am usign MySQL 5.6.
I copied the statement from the workbench 6.0 and just placed `?` wherever I needed.

Even this Gives an error:

```
String sql = "UPDATE `test`.`books` SET `title` = ? WHERE `isbn` = ?;";
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, data);
            ps.setString(2, isbn);
            ps.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Statement executed");
            conn.close();
```

Comment: You can't do `SET ? = ?`. On another topic: why do people use so many quotes to wrap the field names?

Comment: I just copied the exact statement which workbench executes , when you manually make updates.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  I want to provide the user the ability to make changes in column , he desires. How would I do it then?

Comment: You would dynamically build the query, which is dangerous.

Comment: But then i want to use Prepared statement and not create statement.

Comment: No DBMS i'm aware of allows the usage of column/table names as parameters in a prepared SQL statement. You need to use Dynamic SQL instead.

Comment: What exactly is the error that it thrown?

Answer (score 8):

You can build the query dynamically

```
String sql = "UPDATE `test`.`books` SET " + whatToUp + " = ? WHERE `isbn` = ?;";
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, data);
ps.setString(2, isbn);
ps.executeUpdate(); // you need to use the overloaded method without an argument
```

Note that you are then vulnerable to SQL injection.

If for some reason that is wrong, remove all the quotes.

```
String sql = "UPDATE test.books SET " + whatToUp + " = ? WHERE isbn = ?;";
```

If that doesn't work, then your schema doesn't match. That's up to you.

In my rush to answer I didn't see you were using

```
ps.executeUpdate(sql);
```

This method's javadoc says

> Note:This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or
>   CallableStatement.

You have to use

```
ps.executeUpdate();
```

since you've already provided the sql statement to the method.

All of this would've been solved extremely quickly if you had just provided the exception stack trace. Consider that next time you ask a question

Comment: @ArjunVerma You have to obviously change your `PreparedStatement` setters.

Comment: That will still cause an exeception, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18527333/466862)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling [`executeUpdate(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) on a `PreparedStatement`, for which the documentation says:

> `SQLException` - [...], **the method is called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`**

You need to use [`executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) (so without parameters) to execute a `PreparedStatement`. The reason is: a prepared statement already knows its query (the one it was created with), so it makes no sense to provide a query when executing it.

Note that the MySQL implementation is not entirely conforming to JDBC. It actually does allow executing with a `String` here, but it causes a syntax error because of the parameter placeholders.

Your first piece of code will **never** work, because parameters can only be used in places of values, not in places where object names (like table names) are expected.

Answer (score 0):

@SotiriosDelimanolis gave you the answer.

Just build the SQL String differently

```
Stringbuilder sql = new Stringbuilder("UPDATE test.books SET ");
sql.append(whatToUp);
sql.append(" = ? WHERE isbn = ?");
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
ps.setString(1, data);
ps.setString(2, isbn);
ps.executeUpdate(sql.toString());
System.out.println("Statement executed");
conn.close();
```

Comment: @ArjunVerma Do you still have the ';' in the SQL statement?  This is a pretty basic update statement across any database, there's something else going on then,  Either the data datatype doesn't match the column (whatToUp) datatype, or ???

Comment: @Mike - instead of ps.executeUpdate(sql.toString())  you have to use ps.executeUpdate() because you have already passed your `sql.toString()` in 5th statement above. Moreover Javadoc says This method `executeUpdate(arg)`  cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement. You have to call executeUpdate() without argument. Please read answers of [Mark Rotteveel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18527333/1115584) and [Sotirios Delimanolis](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18519578/1115584)